# One Page Website - Navigation Highlight Current Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problems integrating a navigation bar that highlights the current section being viewed on the website. I just want the currently viewed section to be bold in the navigation bar.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpqRXr):

**HTML**

```
  <nav id="nav-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a class="page" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="page" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="page" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a class="page" href="#scrapbook">Scrapbook</a></li>
      <li><a class="page" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="header-content">
    <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" height="200px" width="200px">
    <h3>Joseph Cooper</h3>
    <h3>Graphic Designer</h3>
    <p> 10.03.97 </p>
  </div>

<a href="#about"><img id ="down" src="img/down.png" height="42px" width="42px"></a>
```

Comment: You'll probably need Javscript to do that....what research have you done on that?

Comment: I think that you could be able to do it with [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)

Comment: I tried waypoints but it didn't seem to want to work, and I searched around for other methods and found a few links but none of them seemed to want to work as well?

Answer (score 1):

I added two line of code, one to remove bold from all href in navigation, and one to add bold to href that is clicked. Take a look at codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doaRjy

```
   function smoothScroll (duration) {
      $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {        
          var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

          $("#nav-wrap a").css('font-weight','normal')/*this line remove bold from all href*/
          $(this).css('font-weight','bold')/*this line add bold to clicked href*/

          if( target.length ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, duration);
          }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thats what I had before, it only highlights the link when clit is clicked on. I want the user to be able to scroll down to the 'About' section and the navigation bar will automatically highlight it. Like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Highlighting-The-Current-Nav-Link-with-jQuery/

Comment: You say:  _I just want the currently viewed section to be bold in the navigation bar._ and this script do just that, bold font of selected href.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this by using the jQuery's offset().top and checking it against the window's scrollTop.

```js
var $window = $(window),
  homeLink = $("a[href='#home']"),
  aboutLink = $("a[href='#about']"),
  portfolioLink = $("a[href='#portfolio']");

$window.on("scroll", function(e) {

  if ($window.scrollTop() < $("#about").offset().top) {

    $("#nav-wrap").find("a").css("font-weight", 400);
    homeLink.css("font-weight", 900);

  } else if ($window.scrollTop() > $("#about").offset().top && $window.scrollTop() < $("#portfolio").offset().top) {

    $("#nav-wrap").find("a").css("font-weight", 400);
    aboutLink.css("font-weight", 900);

  }

});
```

Comment: I don't think this is working because all the links are on the same page?

Comment: This is the result I am after - however when I implemented it into my website it still does not work, yet works fine on codepen?

Comment: This also only works on codepen for the Home and About section, I added code for portfolio etc. and it didn't highlight these pages